# Tesseract image to searchable pdf in java

Tags: java, tesseract

I am trying to convert the image to a searchable pdf using tesseract. The below command line option working fine for me.

[image]

Exploring a similar option in java. But not sure what to pass in the arguments. Below is my java code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ValueOf;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;

public class Mask2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File image = new File("D:\\ML\\Java\\img3.PNG");
        Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
        tesseract.setDatapath("C://Program Files//Tesseract-OCR//tessdata");
        tesseract.setLanguage("eng");
        tesseract.setPageSegMode(1);
        tesseract.setOcrEngineMode(1);
        try {

       // Not sure what to pass in arguments
        tesseract.createDocumentsWithResults()
            
            
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions / Solutions would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list of renderFormats like this ( you can add others)

```
List<RenderedFormat> renderFormats = new ArrayList<RenderedFormat>();
                    renderFormats.add(RenderedFormat.PDF);
```

and then you can pass the path of the input filename (PDF or IMG), the path of the output filename with no extension, and the render format you want to use.

```
tesseract.createDocuments("a/b/c/inputfile.PNG", "a/b/c/outputfile", renderFormats);
```

Ciao!